# junos_l2_interface removes description, can it not?

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

junos_l2_interface module removes pre-set interface description and I would like it not to. Is there a way, or should I just redo this using junos_config module?

Running Ansible 2.8.1 on JUNOS 14.1X53-D47.3 and using Juniper.junos role and junos_l2_interface module

My task config:

```
    - name: Setting vlan to interface
      junos_l2_interface:
         name: "{{interface_name}}"
         access_vlan: "{{vlan_name}}"
         unit: "{{unit}}"
         mode: access
```

Output:

```
   changed: [X.X.X.X] => {
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "access_vlan": "vlan622",
            "active": true,
            "aggregate": null,
            "description": null,
            "enhanced_layer": true,
            "filter_input": null,
            "filter_output": null
```

Description: null removes the preset description

Since I do not include description parameter in module I would like the module to leave the description as it is.

Comment: It's invocation `"description": null` of the module. You might want to `"register: result"` and take a look at  [diff](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/junos_l2_interface_module.html#return-values) whether the description has really changed.

Comment: junos_l2_interface is not part of Juniper.Junos roles but comes from core ansible

Comment: @VladimirBotka I have checked from the router's side that the description is really gone